# Symlink for public folder in Laravel application causes redirect

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, url, web, vps

I have a Laravel 5.5 application uploaded on VPS. Here is how directory structure looks like:

```
web
   private
      laravel
         app
         bootstrap
         public
         ...
   public
      laravel
         public (symlink)
      .htaccess
```

I have created symlink from `private/laravel/public` directory to `public/laravel`. Everything works fine, but there is a problem with last slash in url.

When I type `'example.com/posts'` then it is ok, but when i type `'example.com/posts/'` it redirects me to `'example.com/laravel/public/posts'` with working content of `'example.com/posts'`.

How can I avoid it? The url should stay like `'example.com/posts/'`.

.htaccess in web/public directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^laravel/public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a default .htaccess file in laravel project public folder and I had to **delete the following three lines** to stop trailing slash redirecting:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove trailing slash url processing from htacess. Change rewrite rule given my laravel as below in project's htacess 
Write as:

RewriteBase /root/laravel/public

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]